# Django ContextList keys

Tags: python, django, django-testing

Is there a way to get the keys of a returned ContextList object when running a test harness?

If I have:

```
return render_to_response('x.html', 
                              {
                               'one' : 1,
                               'two' : 2,
                               'three' : 3
                               },
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Is there a way to loop through the keys one, two, & three?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```python
keys = []
for subcontext in response.context:
  for d in subcontext.dicts:
    for k in d.keys():
      if k not in keys:
        keys.append(k)

print keys
```